# Can I create an Outlook rule to move a message to a folder and delete the previous message that might exist in that folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, email-filter

We have a system that sends regular status e-mails out.

I have a rule that moves the messages it sends to a folder, but I only really need to keep the latest version of the e-mail.

At the moment I have to go to the folder and clear out any old version of the message, but I'd like for that to happen automatically. Is there a rule I can set up to do this?

Comment: I would be (pleasantly?) surprised if there were a way to do this with an Outlook rule. But I would think it could be scripted to happen asynchronously, by running a task periodically to remove all but the newest message in a particular folder. I'm thinking of cron+python+imaplib, but that makes all sorts of additional assumptions.

Comment: I don't know about making this part of a rule but you can use the "Conversation Cleanup" feature to remove all redundant messages in a folder at once. Right click on the folder in the navigation pane and select "Clean up folder."

Comment: @PeterFitzgerald - I want this to be an automatic process that can run without my interaction.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the default rules in Outlook are rather restrictive.  I suspect it's going to be a quick foray into the disturbed world of VBA to make it work the way you want.

Chances are you'll need to create a macro that runs whenever Outlook receives a mail and as part of that macro empty the other folder and perform the move.

Stack Overflow has a couple of good answers that point at the best way to achieve it:

Firstly there's running the macro on mail received: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263483/how-do-i-trigger-a-macro-to-run-after-a-new-mail-is-received-in-outlook

Then there's deleting all items in a given folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782498/outlook-macro-why-doesnt-this-delete-all-items-from-deleted-folder

Then lastly the moving of the mail item should be a simple move...: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Hmm - I don't want to empty the folder - just delete the previous copy of the e-mail with the same subject. However, I should be able to adapt the second macro...